# Using array of string in C

Tags: c, malloc

I am just practicing to understand dynamic allocation in C. I am getting a segmentation fault error. I am not sure where I made mistake.

```
int wordcount = 5;
char **args = (char**)malloc(wordcount * sizeof(char*));

for ( int i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) {
    args[i] = (char*)malloc(167 * sizeof(char));
}

int c=0;
while(c < wordcount){
    strcpy("hello\n",  args[c]);
    c++;
}
```

Comment: Which documentation to `strcpy()` did you read?

Comment: "*not sure where I made mistake*" a debugger would point you to the line crashing the program.

Comment: It seems all you need is a good [`strcpy` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). By the way, just about any tutorial or book would have told you how to use `strcpy` already.

Comment: Although probably unrelated to your issue: In C there is no need to cast a `void`-pointer, which the result of `malloc()` is.

Comment: You have reversed the arguments to `strcpy()`.  The first argument should be the destination, not the source.

Comment: `strcpy("hello\n",  args[c]);` ==> `strcpy(args[c], "hello\n");`

Comment: @4386427  char **args is array of string  I meant to say.  sorry I will update the qsn.

Comment: Well no, `char ** args;` defines `args` to be a pointer to pointer to `char`. Also there is no data type "string" in C.

Comment: thanks  for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy `args[c]` to the location of the `"hello\n"` string, which is in read only memory, you should change the order of the parameters.